# Can an Azure function listen to multiple EventGrid Events?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have an Azure function which contains some generic logic to sync some database information. Currently, this is exposed via three functions to cover three separate events, and isn't quite as DRY as I'd like. Is it possible to have a singular function listen to the three different events and execute only once in the event all three fire at once? I have yet to find any documentation that suggests it could be done.

Comment: are you using the out of the box event grid trigger ? You could always point multiple subscription to the same endpoint or do this using an http trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Event Grid is an eventing Pub/Sub model for distributing an event interest to the destination resource in the reliable way and **PUSH** manner. There is no listener for consumer of the event interest.

The event interest in this model can be distributed in the **FAN-IN** and/or **FAN-OUT** Patterns.

Your scenario can be achieved using the FAN-IN Pattern, where multiple subscriptions are using the same destination resource such as an Azure Function, see the following screen snippet:

[image]

Note, that each subscription in this distributed eventing model has owned metadata (topic, filtering, retry policy, etc.) for handling a managing delivery of the event message to the destination resource.

In the case, when the event interest source (topic) is the same, you can use a single subscription with an advanced pre-filtering of your interest and the detail filtering in the subscriber code.